# sqlite concept to coredata concept?

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-data

i am using Normal Sqlite concept with sqlite file for storing data
updating data based on primaryKey,selecting record through foreign key.is it possible to convert my sqlite concept to core data concept(coding also for inserting,selecting,updating) completely.Coredata is object graph framework(not database).How can i code for primary key,foreign key? any example or tutorial to achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

There's a tutorial on iPhone developer site [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html). And there are several [sample codes](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/index.html?section=Resource+Types&topic=Sample+C#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code) with Core Data as well. These should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good [tutorial for beginners](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html), I actually just went through today.  This is a one table implementation.  Look at the next steps for some more advanced version with multi-table versions of the same app.

It is a very good walk through and talks you all the different aspects.